# Magento2 Website showing "nil" value on home page

Tags: magento2

Magento2 website showing "nil" value when hit URL of website.
[image]

Comment: have you checked you index.php, is there any `die` statement!

Comment: No any die in index.php

Comment: you can search for text nil in your directory.also check log and enable error reporting.

Comment: I should be some error happening.Please check PHP error and apache log

Comment: CPU usage going on 400% then issue showing. Mysql database having issues. Any solution for that?